# Woocommerce Вывод новых товаров по определённым критериям

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wp-query

Нужно вывести 20 последних товаров, но только те, у которых есть Фото и они в наличии. Вот мои попытки:

```
add_action( 'recent_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {

    $query->set( 'meta_query', 
        array( 
            'relation' => 'AND',

            //если в наличии
            array(
               'key' => '_stock_status',
               'value' => 'instock',
               'compare' => '='
           ),

            //если есть фото
            array(
               'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
               'value' => '0',
               'compare' => '>'
           ),
        )
    ); 

}

do_action( 'recent_query' );
```

1. Вывод мне непонятен, в общем это не то в любом случае

   ```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',

    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    foreach ($query as $item) {
        echo '<pre style="display: none">' . var_dump($item->post_title) . '</pre>';
    }
   ```
2. Выводит все товары. Т.к. мне нужно понимать, если изображение, этот подход не работает, потому что дефолтное изображение тоже считается, что есть.

   ```
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        'orderby' => 'date', 
    );

    $iwposts = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    foreach( $iwposts as $post ){ 
        setup_postdata($post);

          var_dump($post);
          echo '<hr/>';  
      }
    wp_reset_postdata();
   ```
3. Почти аналог того, что выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'product',
     'orderby' => 'date',
     'order'   => 'DESC',
     'posts_per_page' => 20, 
     'meta_query' => (
                                 'relation' => 'AND',
                                  array(
                                                 'key' => '_stock_status',
                                                 'value' => 'instock',
                                                 'compare' => '='
                                 ),
                                 //если есть фото
                                 array(
                                                 'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
                                 ),
                      )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

foreach ($query as $item) {
     echo '<pre style="display: none">' . var_dump($item->post_title) . '</pre>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Выдавало сначала критическую ошибку, но я чуть подправил код и в целом всё ок. 'relation' => 'AND', - надо убрать. В _thumbnail_id надо добавить 'compare' => 'EXISTS'

Answer (score 0):

И оба array() нужно заключить ещё в один array().
Вот рабочий пример с исправлениями от "Рома Хр" и исправленным выводом:

```html
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 20, 
        'meta_query' => ( array(
            array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'instock'                
            ),
            array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXIST'
            ) )
        )
    );
           
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
         wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
       } else {
         echo __( 'Продуктов не найдено' );
       }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```